# Discord.py Command Permissions Error & Command Argument Error Doesn't Work Properly

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this code which is supposed to send a error  when it is missing arguments or when the user doesn't have permissions. But it doesn't run any of the errors when they are supposed to happen. Tho I know the kick_error function runs because of the `print("error")`

```py
    @commands.command(name='kick')
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):        
        await ctx.guild.kick(member)
        await ctx.send(f'**{member}** has been kicked.')

    @kick.error
    async def kick_error(self, error, ctx):
        print("error")
        if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
            await ctx.send("Looks like you don't have the perm.")
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send("Missing argument")
```

Comment: Could you add `print(type(error))` after `print("error")`? Maybe the error is of different type then you are checking it against.

Comment: Its gives `<class 'discord.ext.commands.context.Context'>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched the positions of the arguments. Try this:

```py
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    print("error")
    if isinstance(error, commands.CheckFailure):
        await ctx.send("Looks like you don't have the perm.")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Missing argument")
```

Notice that `ctx` is the first argument to `kick_error` and `error` is the second one.